# Ruby on Rails code for taking a screenshot of different sections of a page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fonts, png, snapshot

I am creating a Ruby on Rails app. A specific page in my app is divided into several sections by `<div>` tags. Each `<div>` includes a combination of text (using different fonts), symbols and mathematic formulas. I use MathJax and a few other Javascript codes to display them correctly and everything works great on my computer. However Javascript is not enabled on everyone's browser and some Javascript codes might not load correctly on some other people's browsers. One solution I was thinking is this: after all the javascripts are done processing and the page is displayed correctly on my computer (server) I use some code to generate a snapshot of each `<div>` in PNG and send them to the server (for example I click a `<button>` tag on the page to activate this code after I'm happy what is displayed is correct). Then I'll save these images in the database and serve them which will look the same on everyone's computer regardless of whether Javascript is enabled, what browser they're using, etc. Is anyone aware of a code or command that I can use? Please note, currently after the page is loaded, Javascripts process the HTML content and produce the correct display. Also I don't want to take a snapshot of the whole page; snapshot of each `<div>` separately.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a client-side problem, here is a javascript that will work for you http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bit of a problem there. Javascript is not executed until the page has finished loading, i.e. all of the information has already been sent to the client. You're not executing javascript at the server level, so you wouldn't be able to do that kind of processing at all. If they have javascript disabled, your code will never get executed.

You could generate the images using Imagemagick or something similar, I know PHP has bindings for that. There are a couple of extremely messy solutions like rendering it in a browser on the server side with something like selenium, but I definitely wouldn't recommend doing that. Overall, it depends on the platform on which your developing, but most major languages have support for generating images that don't require 100% javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe I didn't explain well. What I want to do is that (for example) after the page is completely rendered and displayed correctly on my computer/server, I use a code/function (probably a Javascript that I activate by clicking a `<button>` tag on the page) to take a snapshot of each of `<div>` tags on the page.

Comment: Right, but the scenario that you described had javascript disabled. Which is why this wouldn't be possible.